# error of adding an image to a map by multithreading from C# VS2013 WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, visual-studio, backgroundworker

I would like to add an image to a map based on OpenStreetMap from C# VS2013 WPF desktop application.

But, the time of generating the image may be long so I need to use multithreading to do this. In main thread, I created a new thread to draw and add the image to the WPF desktop application.

In single thread, it works well. But, in multithreading, no image can be added to the map.

The code is as follows:

```
 using System.ComponentModel;
 private BackgroundWorker worker_addImage;
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        worker_addImage = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker_addImage.DoWork += (s, a) =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("the worker started \r\n");
            DrawImage();
        };
        _worker_addImage.ProgressChanged += _worker_ProgressChanged;
        _worker_addImage.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, a) =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("image added \r\n");
            AddImage();
        };
    }

    private void ShowImage_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Show Image \r\n");
        if (worker_addImage.IsBusy == false)
            worker_addImage.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    // why this progress function is not executed ? 
    private static void _worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ProgressPercentage.ToString());
    }
```

**UPDATE**

This is the code that add image to the map.

```
    private void AddImage()
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(resultImageString, UriKind.Absolute);
        System.Windows.Media.ImageSource imgSource = new BitmapImage(uri);
        // the image generated by DrawImage() is saved in this URI. I can 
        // open and see it. But, it cannot be added to the map. But, if I
        // used single thread, no problems.
        mapImage.Source = imgSource;  
    }
```

In DrawImage(). I saved the image in a local folder as a png file.
But, in AddImage(), I was told that **the png file cannot be accessed because another thread or process was using it.** Why ?

Is that due to that RunWorkerCompleted handler is invoked in the UI thread but the png file was being used by the "worker_addImage" thread ?

```
      using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
      {
               using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(res, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {
                    myImage.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Png);
                    byte[] bytes = memory.ToArray();
                    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
      }
```

Comment: You would create the image in the `DoWork` handler (which runs on a background thread), but add the image in the `RunWorkerCompleted` handler, because it is invoked ín the UI thread, and you therefore can access UI elements. There is no need to call `CancelAsync`, because the worker has already completed. The `ProgressChanged` handler is only called when you call `ReportProgress` from `DoWork` (which you certainly don't do yet). In order to actually run the BackgroundWorker, you would of course have to call `RunWorkerAsync`. Read the MSDN documentation of the BackgroundWorker class!

Comment: @Clemens, I have updated the code in OP based on your idea but, still no image added. thanks !

Comment: Looks ok. However, you don't need to use the Dispatcher here, because (as already said) the RunWorkerCompleted handler is invoked in the UI thread.

Comment: @Clemens, I removed the Dispatcher , but, still no image added. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing RunWorkerAsync() on worker_addImage. Also message box should be marshalled as your process is not in the main UI thread.

Comment: I have added RunWorkerAsync() but still cannot get the image added to the map. thanks !

Comment: what is inside your DrawImageAndAdd() function? If you put a breakpoint in there, what happens?

Comment: DrawImageAndAdd() created a bitmap image (.png) and saved it in a folder. I used a lib (called XAML map control lib xamlmapcontrol.codeplex.com) to add the image to the map. If I ran the code in single thread, the image can be added well. But, if I ran it by multithreading, no image can be added. If I put a breakpoint inside the function, no errors popped up.

Comment: Is it hitting the breakpoint inside DrawImageAndAdd in multithreading mode? I can help better if you can edit the code for the function in your quesion,